# IO work item vs non-IO work item

Tags: multithreading, winapi, io

I am reading about the old windows threading system and there is a distinction that I don't understand, from msdn you can read the following :

*"There are two types of worker threads in the thread pool: I/O and non-I/O. An I/O worker thread is a thread that waits in an alertable wait state. Work items are queued to I/O worker threads as asynchronous procedure calls (APC). You should queue a work item to an I/O worker thread if it should be executed in a thread that waits in an alertable state."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686756(v=vs.85).aspx

Why would you want to use a IO worker thread vs a non one ? Can you still do IO operation like reading a file in a non IO worker thread ? 
Thanks

Comment: Mind to share the link?